# Why does ARKit require iOS 11 and an A9 when other sdks liek Vuforia or Wikitude can do the same? with lower iOS versions

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, vuforia, arcore, wikitude

I'm asking myself why ARKit and also ARCore require higher OS Versions than other SDKs like Vuforia or Wikitude? It seems like they can do what ARKit and ARCore also can do. Or are there some limitations when it comes to tracking?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ARKit is a framework contained in the iOS framework and (my guess is) it relies on other parts of the framework in order to function. Not only that, but all native frameworks are bundled and distributed through iOS updates, in comparison to frameworks like Vuforia and Wikitude which are completely separate and don't rely on internal iOS frameworks.

Not only this, but frameworks like ARKit and ARCore do a lot more than the other two examples by utilizing the devices' hardware to ensure better accuracy and to deliver an overall better experience.

These techniques are quite demanding computationally so it would make sense for the A9 chip to be a requirement in order to carry out the calculations required to achieve this accuracy, and this is on top of the graphical requirements in the ARKit framework.